# How do I add friends in Send Anywhere?

Tags: send-anywhere

I am using [Send Anywhere](https://send-anywhere.com/) for online file sharing on a desktop computer, and I can see no way of adding friends, either in my browser or in the desktop program.  Is this possible? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Send a file with the 6 digit number:

[image]

[image]

Enter the key on your second device, and receive the file:

[image]
[image]

Yay, fwends!

[image]